# details tag missing from $_POST

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I'm working on a php school project and i have to use the details and summary tags, my problem is that when i submit my form all the fields are in $_POST but not the content of `<details>`

i know a form submits based on the name so i gave it name and id, is it normal?

here is the fieldset from the form :

```
<legend>SITE</legend>
<details id="SITE[comment]" name="SITE[comment]">
<summary>aide</summary>
<p>titre : nom de votre site affiché dans l'entête<br>
           couleur : de ce titre (format html ou css)<br>
           image : nom du dossier des images
</p></details><br>

<label for="SITE[titre]">titre</label>
<input id="SITE[titre]" name="SITE[titre]" value="Welcome" required="" size="25" type="text"><br>

<label for="SITE[couleur]">couleur</label>
<input id="SITE[couleur]" name="SITE[couleur]" class="color" value="#FFF" '="" type="text"><br>

<label for="SITE[images]">images</label>
<input id="SITE[images]" name="SITE[images]" value="img" required="" size="25" type="text">
<br>
```

Comment: Can you add more context, can you show the whole form tag used to post and the PHP you are using to try and get the post data?

Comment: Only form `input`, `select` and `textarea` elements are submitted with a form.

Comment: ahh... i should have known it. thank you!!

Comment: As @doublesharp says, only form elements are submitted with a form.

Comment: careful dealing with `input type=checkbox`

Comment: What's `value="#FFF" '="" type="text"`?

Answer (score 0):

Only the values of successful form controls will be included in submitted form data. Form controls include `input`, `select`, `textarea` and `button`.

The `<details>` element is not a form control.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap everything in form tags and place a submit button

```
<form method="post" name="phpFileName" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
 <legend>SITE</legend>
 <details id="SITE[comment]" name="SITE[comment]">
 <summary>aide</summary>
 <p>titre : nom de votre site affiché dans l'entête<br>
       couleur : de ce titre (format html ou css)<br>
       image : nom du dossier des images
</p></details><br>

 <label for="SITE[titre]">titre</label>
 <input id="SITE[titre]" name="SITE[titre]" value="Welcome" required="" size="25" type="text"><br>

 <label for="SITE[couleur]">couleur</label>
 <input id="SITE[couleur]" name="SITE[couleur]" class="color" value="#FFF" '="" type="text"><br>

 <label for="SITE[images]">images</label>
 <input id="SITE[images]" name="SITE[images]" value="img" required="" 
size="25" type="text">
 <br>
</form>
```